# bind select change to dropzone.js event

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

When I init my dropzone, I have a button that clears all of the dropzone files

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
       init: function () {
            var myDropZone = this;
            $("#buttonID").click(function () {
                        myDropZone.removeAllFiles();
                    }
            );
```

I have a HTML SELECT with the id of "project" that when changed, I also want the dropzone files to clear.
I tried this:

```
    Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
   init: function () {
        var myDropZone = this;
        $("#buttonID").click(function () {
                    myDropZone.removeAllFiles();
                }
        );

        $("#project").change(function () {
                    myDropZone.removeAllFiles();
                }
        );
```

as well as

```
    $("#project").bind("change",function () {
                myDropZone.removeAllFiles();
            }
    );
```

But neither work. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've found.
I was creating the form element dynamically and no matter what I did, I could not init dropzone. The form had to exist (I hid it and displayed it when needed) when the page loaded and then it would init and run fine.
I must not understand how to init this correctly when created dynamically.